# Corona SDK, display.contentWidth and height does not get the expected values

Tags: corona-sdk

I'm drawing a simple rectangle to fill the entire screen.

```
local bg=display.newRect(0,0,display.contentWidth,display.contentHeight)
```

Instead of drawing a full screen rectangle, all i get is this:

[image]

How do i rectify this?

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with _config.lua_. Take a look at this and I hope you found some help from it [http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/04/the-ultimate-config-lua-file/](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/04/the-ultimate-config-lua-file/)

Comment: I have gone through that.It i tried using letterbox scaling, didn't work. Posted it on [http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/50616-displaycontentwidth-and-height-not-returning-expected-values/#entry262368]  those suggestions did not work either

Comment: try this local bg=display.newRect(display.contentCenterX,display.contentCenterY,display.contentWidth,display.contentHeight)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its anchor points is in the middle of the object.
do this:

```
bg.anchorX = 0; bg.anchorY = 0;
```

from [here](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/10/15/tutorial-anchor-points-in-graphics-2-0/)

Answer (score 1):

the x and y value 0 start from the middle of the screen so

this should start far upper left

```
local bg=display.newRect(0,0,display.content‌​Width,display.contentHeight)
```

while this should start from the content center and then sets the image width and height according to screen dimensions

```
local bg=display.newRect(display.contentCenterX,display.contentCenterY,display.content‌​Width,display.contentHeight)
```